# Logic is missing in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi,

A button which is adjacent to an input. The button is hidden by default and will be visible when the input gets focus and it will be hidden again if the input loses focus.

I wrote a code to achieve that. But the problem is button's event is not being triggered since it is hidden the moment the input loses focus.

I am not getting any idea to achieve that.Can somebody help me.

Here is the code

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
  .icon{
   visibility:hidden;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

   <input type="text" onFocus="onOver('f4_1')" onBlur="onOut('f4_1')"/>
   <input type="button" class="icon" value="?" id="f4_1" onClick="alert('hi..')"/>

<script>
    function onOver(f4Id){
      document.getElementById(f4Id).style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function onOut(f4Id){
        document.getElementById(f4Id).style.visibility="hidden";
    }
</script>
 </body>

</html>
```

**Note:** Use pure javascript to achieve. Don't use any jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry...typing mistake..question is edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handling is very important and understanding when they are fired is utmost important
    `onmousedown` event will override onBlur effect of textbox ,which is what is required.

check working  **[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypg92/)**

```
   <input type="text" onFocus="onOver('f4_1')" onBlur="onOut('f4_1')"/>
   <input type="button" class="icon" value="?" id="f4_1" onmousedown="alert('M Kicked')"/>

<html>
 <head>
 <style>
  .icon{
   visibility:hidden;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

   <input type="text" onFocus="onOver('f4_1')" onBlur="onOut('f4_1')"/>
   <input type="button" class="icon" value="?" id="f4_1" onmousedown="alert('M Kicked')"/>

<script>
    function onOver(f4Id){
      document.getElementById(f4Id).style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function onOut(f4Id){
        document.getElementById(f4Id).style.visibility="hidden";
    }
</script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the order of these events varies between browsers. If I remember correctly, Internet Explorer will trigger the button if you click on it, whereas Firefox will not.

Anyway, the problem can be fixed by adding a small delay. Change your `onOut` function to:

```
function onOut(f41d) {
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(f41d).style.visibllity="hidden";},25);
}
```

Now the button will hide almost instantly. It should be unnoticeable to the human eye, but the computer can tell the difference and allow you to click the button.

Comment: I checked it in IE9.. In this way, button is not being hidden if input loses foucs....Can you please check it in your system once...